# Cannot make a simple http request on android, no error just doesn't work

Tags: android, http

I tried to build a simple app which will send a http post request to control some program. Here is my AsyncTask class for calling a request.

```
class CallURL extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground(String... command) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url= new URL("http://192.168.1.20:13579/command.html");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            String query = URLEncoder.encode("wm_command="+command[0],"UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The app can be built and run just fine but when i click the button, it just give me this

```
10-12 18:27:08.167 8484-8484/com.example.nattawit.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
10-12 18:27:08.257 8484-8484/com.example.nattawit.myapplication I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
10-12 18:27:08.274 8484-9196/com.example.nattawit.myapplication D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
10-12 18:27:08.274 8484-9196/com.example.nattawit.myapplication D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
10-12 18:27:08.310 8484-9196/com.example.nattawit.myapplication D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
10-12 18:27:08.310 8484-9196/com.example.nattawit.myapplication D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
```

there's no exception or error or anything. No clue what I need to fix. (Also, I already put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my manifests)

Comment: Did you check that your server running correctly?

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Use any of the several http client libraries out there...

Comment: What is the connection between you clicking a button and your AsyncTask class?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari At first I tried using Apache HTTP Client but then i find out that as android 6.0 is released, the Apache HTTP Client has been removed and they recommended to use the HttpURLConnection class instead
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: use retrofit or aquery or okhttp or ...

Comment: @greenapps I has a function which called CallURL().execute()
public void clickStop(View view){
        new CallURL().execute("890");
    }
and in the layout I add attribute `android:onClick="clickStop"` to my button

Comment: @SaeedEntezari I'll try that, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: 'http post request to control some program'. Please explain how that should be done. Of course you will have errors or exceptions. Just look better in your LogCat. What you posted now from your LogCat has nothing to do with your code. Put log statements in doInBackground so you can see how your code flows. Add log statements to that catch block too otherwise you stay blindly looking. Return a message string from doInBackground which tells if all went ok or not. Add an onPosExecute where you can display that message in a Toast for example.

Comment: ' urlConnection.connect();'. That is much too late of course as you have already written the info. Just remove that line. Not needed.

Comment: @greenapps To be specifics, I want to control media player classics which already has a bulit-in http server. All I need to do is just send the correct post request. As for logcat, that's all there is, everything before that line is just initialize app and every time I push button it gave me only these 6 lines. I have tried to put log in there but it still seems to run smoothly until the end of function.

Comment: 'seems to run smoothly'. That is not enough. You should be sure. I told you what you have to do to be sure.